# Asynchronous SOAP request to service generated by wsdl2java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, asynchronous, wsdl

I followed the examples here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html (Part "Asynchronous Invocation Model")

They show how to call the generated code with `port.greetMeSometimeAsync()`. Yes, this is possible, because from the WSDL's `greetMeSometime` operation three methods were created:

```
public Future<?> greetMeSometimeAsync(
  String requestType,
  AsyncHandler<org.myorg.types.GreetMeSometimeResponse> asyncHandler
);

public Response<org.myorg.types.GreetMeSometimeResponse> greetMeSometimeAsync(
   String requestType);

public java.lang.String greetMeSometime(
   String requestType
);
```

But when I send a SOAP request containing:

```
<greetMeSometimeAsync>
   <requestType>some string</requestType>
</greetMeSometimeAsync>
```

The SOAP fault is returned:

```
Message part greetMeSometimeAsync was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)
```

Of course not. The greetMeSometimeAsync is only in the generated code. The original not async method works flawlessly:

```
<greetMeSometime>
   <requestType>some string</requestType>
</greetMeSometime>
```

Is there a way to tell `wsdl2java` to treat `greetMeSometime` as asynchronous method without appending the "Async" suffix?

Or is there any other alternative solution to provide an asynchronous SOAP UI generated by wsdl2java?

Comment: You just want the generated asynchronous Java method to have a different name? Why?

Comment: I just wanted to implement the async method and don't want to care about the synchronous method. But the SOAP request calls only the synchronous method...

Comment: Ok, the asynchronous stuff is all under the covers on your end. Absolutely nothing changes about what goes over the wire; it's just whether your code waits for the result, or whether you get a `Response` you can check later (or provide an `AsyncHandler`)... which probably only makes sense if the SOAP call is going to take seconds to return or if you're doing a whole bunch of them at once.